# Queryset for models FK relations in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

These are my models and fields:

## Models.py

- Course:

  - title
  - slug
- CoursePrerequisite

  - this_course = ForeignKey(Course)
  - prerequisite_of_course = ForeignKey(Course)
- Curriculum:

  - course = ForeignKey(Course,)
  - title
  - slug
- Enrollment:

  - student = ForeignKey(User)
  - curriculum =ForeignKey(Curriculum)
  - date

**Brif of my system:**

> 1. As seen from my model file, in this system, the courses have a
>    pre-requisite state.Untile preson can't pass  pre-requisite of course, can't take the course.
> 2. Each course is presented for enrollment in model named:
>    'Curriculum'.

**And finally my problem is:**

In fact, I know that I must first check student enrollment and find the 'Curriculum' that he have,and  by this, find all course of student. Then,among the course I will find the course that have prerequisite_of_course and finally check for student for each of this prerequisite course check that student enroll in course curriculum!

**It's very hard for me to write this query? Can you help me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, this can help your query

```
# all student enrollments
all_enrollment = Enrollement.objects.filter(student=user)


# all students  curriculum_ids
all_curriculum_ids =  all_enrollment.values_list('curriculum', flat=True)

# all curriculum object list
all_curriculum = Curriculum.objects.filter(pk__in=all_curriculum_ids)


#  all student curriculum courses
all_courses_ids = all_curriculum.values_list('course', flat=True)

# we have all courses that student participated
all_courses = Course.objects.filter(pk__in=all_courses_ids)


# Now getting prerequisite_of_course ids
all_prerequisite_of_course_ids = CoursePrerequisite.objects.filter(this_course=this_course,prerequisite_course__isnull=False).value_list('prerequisite_course')


# here checking if student took all prequisite courses
for prerequisite_of_course_id in all_prerequisite_of_course_ids:
    if all_courses.filter((pk__in=prerequisite_of_course_id).exists():
        print("Paticipated")
    else:
        print("In this course id student did not participated", prerequisite_of_course_id)
        print("Tell Student to go and complete this course")
```

Comment: thanks. I got this error `Cannot resolve keyword 'prerequisite_of_course_isnull' into field. Choices are: created_date, id, modified_date, prerequisite_course, prerequisite_course_id, slug, this_course, this_course_id` @sanjay-kumar

Comment: I think that `all_prerequisite_of_course_ids` must be the filter of `this_course=this_course` rather that filter of `this_course__in=all_courses` . Is it correct? @sanjay-kumar

Comment: oh, it is one extra underscore __isnull=False that is checking that this prerequisite_of_course is not empty

Comment: then you wouldn't have all prerequisite courses ids list to compare with student courses

Comment: Now this error rise: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'value_list'`@sanjay-kumar

Comment: it is values_list just typo

Comment: OK, The problem was gone! but in this line: `if not all_courses.filter(id=prerequisite_of_course_id).exists():` rise this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'`@sanjay-kumar

Comment: And I'm still at about 99% sure I have to put 1 in potatoes. Because we need to find the courses of `this_course` that are pre requisite of `this_course`(Do not forget that: `this_course` is  course that the current user wants to take). It is true?@sanjay-kumar

Comment: Thanks for your patience in solving my problem @sanjay-kumar

Comment: change this if all_courses.filter(pk__in=[prerequisite_of_course_id]).exists():
        print("Paticipated") print prerequisite_of_course_id type and see what it is

Comment: Done sanjay  :))) Thanks a lot for your help. I edit your answer to final answer. @sanjay-kumar